# Trying to convert a console application to a Windows Form in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a Console Application in Visual Studio 2012 that calculates a loan based on principle, loan, and interest.  I am now trying to convert this console application to a Windows form. I feel like this process should be a matter of just switch out the Console prompts and replacing it with Windows Forms txt and radio buttons.
Here is my code for the console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MortgageCalculator
{
    public class MortgageCalculator
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declare variables
            double principle = 0; 
            double years = 0;
            double interest = 0;
            string principleInput, yearsInput, interestInput;


            // User input for Principle amount in dollars
            Console.Write("Enter the loan amount, in dollars(0000.00): ");
            principleInput = Console.ReadLine();
            principle = double.Parse(principleInput);
            //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
            if (principle < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value for the mortgage cannot be a negative value");
            principle = 0;
        }


        // User input for number of years
        Console.Write("Enter the number of years: ");
        yearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
        years = double.Parse(yearsInput);
        //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
        if (years < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Years cannot be a negative value");
            years = 0;
        }

        // User input for interest rate
        Console.Write("Enter the interest rate(%): ");
        interestInput = Console.ReadLine();
        interest = double.Parse(interestInput);
        //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
        if (interest < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value for the interest rate cannot be a negative value");
            interest = 0;
        }

        //Calculate the monthly payment
        //ADD IN THE .Net function call Math.pow(x, y) to compute xy (x raised to the y power). 
        double loanM = (interest / 1200.0);
        double numberMonths = years * 12;
        double negNumberMonths = 0 - numberMonths;
        double monthlyPayment = principle * loanM / (1 - System.Math.Pow((1 + loanM),   negNumberMonths));

        //double totalPayment = monthlyPayment;


        //Output the result of the monthly payment
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The amount of the monthly payment is: {0}{1:0.00}", "$", monthlyPayment));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to end. . .");
        Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

I now want to convert the above to a Windows Form Application.  My desired  design is for my form with principle as a textbox, I then have three radio button controls. One for 15 years, 30 years, and Other(which is another textbox).  The interest rate is a ComboBox with rates from 1-15 percent. This is my first attempt at creating a Windows Form and I will display what I have so far below.  I guess my main problem is working with the calculation of my monthlyPayment and how to import it into a Windows Form App. Any help to the right direction would be appreciated.

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace LoanCalc
   {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           tbLoanDuration.Enabled = false;
       }

       private void rb30years_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (rbOther.Checked)
               tbLoanDuration.Enabled = true;
           else
               tbLoanDuration.Enabled = false;
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

          if (cbLoanRate.SelectedIndex > -1)
           {
               string s = cbLoanRate.SelectedItem.ToString();
           }

           string msg = string.Format("Your total monthly payment is", MonthlyPayment);



        }

       private void tbLoanDuration_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           double years = 0;
           Control ctrl = (Control)sender;

           bool success = Double.TryParse(tbLoanDuration.Text, out years);
           if (!success)
           {
               errorProvider1.SetError(ctrl, "This is not a valid number");
           }  
           else
           {
               errorProvider1.SetError(ctrl, "");
           }

       }

       private double MonthlyPayment()
       {
           double loanM = (interest / 1200.0);
           double numberMonths = years * 12;
           double negNumberMonths = 0 - numberMonths;
           double monthlyPayment = principle * loanM / (1 - System.Math.Pow((1 + loanM), negNumberMonths));

           return monthlyPayment;
       }




       public double interest { get; set; }
       public double years { get; set; }
       public double principle { get; set; }

       private void tbPrinciple_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           double principle = Double.Parse(tbPrinciple.Text);
           //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
           if (principle < 0)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("The value for the mortgage cannot be a negative value");
               principle = 0;
           }
       } 
    }

}
```

Comment: We can't go through all your code and make it work for you. *What is/are the problem(s) you have encountered* ?

Comment: A couple things I noticed:  First, shouldn't `string.Format("Your total monthly payment is", MonthlyPayment);` i Button1_Click be `string.Format("Your total monthly payment is {0}{1:0.00}", "$", monthlyPayment());`?  Secondly, your Console.WriteLine tbPrinciple_TextChanged should probably be a `MessageBox`.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I am having problems importing the calculation.  Does it seem to be in the correct spot?

Comment: @DaBulls33 - There's a few issues with your displaying the calculation...I'm working on an answer for you and should have it up shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PhaDaPhunk said, letting us know exactly what the problem(s) you are encountering (error messages, not sure how to get data, etc) is very helpful to us in helping you.  Based on the generality of your question, I see a few things, a couple of which I put in my comment and I'll elaborate here.

You define three properties in your code:

```
   public double interest { get; set; }
   public double years { get; set; }
   public double principle { get; set; }
```

On a stylistic note, properties are usually capitilized (i.e, `public double Interest`).

It looks like you're assigning values to these properties when the corresponding controls have a change in their value or selected item - at least sometimes.  I'd make the following changes to your code:

```
private void rb30years_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (rb15Years.Checked)
    {
        years = 15;
        tbLoanDuration.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (rb30Years.Checked)
    {
        years = 30;
        tbLoanDuration.Enabled = false;
    }       
    else if (rbOther.Checked)
    {
        tbLoanDuration.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing on what your 15 and 30 year radio button id's are.  This also assigns a value to the `year` property if they select 15 or 30.

For your calculation, you need to call the method and format the return result to the string:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    double selectedRate = 0;

    if (cbLoanRate.SelectedIndex > 1 && double.TryParse(cbLoanRate.SelectedItem, out selectedRate))
    {
        interest = selectedRate;

        lblMonthlyPayment.Text = string.Format("Your total monthly payment is {0}{1:0.00}", "$", MonthlyPayment());
    }
}
```

This is where the bulk of the changes are.

First, if the selectedIndex of cbLoanRate is greater than 1, and the selected item can be converted to a double, then do the calculations, otherwise do nothing (or show an error).

If the selectedIndex is greater than 1 and the selected item can be parsed to a doulbe, assign the result of `selectedRate` to the `interest` property.

I'm not sure what you intended to do with `msg`, but let's say you have a `Label` called `lblMonthlyPayment`, to show the monthly payment.  I used the same string format you had in the console app, and called your method `MonthlyPayment()` directly.  It looks like you were trying to use `monthlyPayment` from the `MonthlyPayment` method, and that won't work as it is only in scope (accessible) inside the method.  Then the return value of your method is assigned to `lblMonthlyPayment`'s Text property.

Finally, I would change your `tbPrinciple_TextChanged` a little as well:

```
   private void tbPrinciple_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       // Use TryParse instead of Parse in case the user enters text or some
       // other non-numeric character
       double enteredPrinciple = 0;

       if (double.TryParse(tbPrincipal.Text, out enteredPrinciple))
       {
           if (enteredPrinciple < 0)
           {
               // Console.WriteLine won't display anything to the user
               MessageBox.Show("The value for the mortgage cannot be a negative value");
           }
           else
           {
               // Assign it to the property
               principle = enteredPrinciple;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           // Prompt the user to enter a numeric value
           MessageBox.Show("The value for the mortgage must be a numeric value");
       }
   }
```

Finally, slight changes to your `tbLoanDuration_TextChanged` method:

```
   private void tbLoanDuration_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Use a different name for the out parameter than your property
       // to avoid confusion
       double enteredYears = 0;

       // This is unnecessary
       Control ctrl = (Control)sender;

       if (Double.TryParse(tbLoanDuration.Text, out enteredYears))
       {
           years = enteredYears;
           errorProvider1.SetError(ctrl, "");
       }  
       else
       {
           years = 0;
           errorProvider1.SetError(ctrl, "This is not a valid number");
       }
   }
```

Most of these changes are minor - all in all you're on the right path.  I haven't tested this code, and haven't done WinForms in about 2 years, so there may be a few syntactic issues, but this should point you in the right direction.